# Delete specific Row in Django

Tags: django, html-table, row

I am pretty new to Django and HTML and want to create a Customer Portal where customers can manage their documents. My problem is that every row has its own delete button but whichever button I click, it always deletes the top row and not the button on the row I clicked. I think you only need to see the template to see the mistake because it deletes the 'Akte' but just not the right one.

Template:

```
<table class="center" id="myTable" style="border:solid;border-color:white;padding-bottom:1%;padding-left:1%;margin-top:3%;border-radius:6px;width:50%">
        <tr style="margin-left:30%;margin-right:30%;border:solid;border-color:white;padding-bottom:1%;padding-left:1%;margin-top:3%;border-radius:6px;color:white">
            <th class="cell" onclick="sortTable(0)">Aktenbarcode</th>
            <th class="cell" onclick="sortTable(1)">Ersteller</th>
            <th class="cell" onclick="sortTable(2)">Startdatum</th>            
            <th class="cell" onclick="sortTable(3)">Kundennummer</th>
            <th class="cell" onclick="sortTable(4)">Aktionen</th>   
        </tr>
        {%for Akte in akte_list%}
        <tr>
            <td id="{{Akte.Aktenbarcode}}"class="cell">{{Akte.Aktenbarcode}}</td>
            <td class="cell">{{Akte.user}}</td>
            <td class="cell">{{Akte.Startdatum}}</td>
            <td class="cell">{{Akte.kundennr}}</td>
            <td class="cell">
            <form action="{% url 'aktedelete' %}" method="post">
                   {% csrf_token %}
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Status anzeigen"/> 
                <input type="hidden" name="aktenbarcode" value="{{Akte.Aktenbarcode}}" />
                <input type="hidden" name="mitglied" value="{{container}}"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="benutzer" value="{{request.user.username}}"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="status" value="{{status}}" />
                {% if status == "O" %}

                <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" type="button"> Akte entfernen</button> 
                                <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle" style="color:black">Akte: {{Akte.Aktenbarcode}}</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" style="color:black">
        Wollen Sie diese Akte unwiderruflich aus dem Container löschen?
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" onclick="form_submit()">Ja, ich bin mir sicher</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel">Nein</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ModalEnd-->   

                </form></td>
                {% endif %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}

        </table>
```

On my modal class:

```
Akte: {{Akte.Aktenbarcode}}
```

This variable also always show the 'Akte' from the first row and not from the row on which I clicked the button. I hope you can give me an explanation and maybe a solution why this happens.

This is in the views.py:

```
def aktedelete(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AkteDelForm()
        z = AkteForm
        container = request.POST['mitglied']
        closecontainerform = CloseContainerForm
        status = request.POST['status']
        aktenbarcode = request.POST.get('aktenbarcode')  
        akte = Akte.objects.get(Aktenbarcode=aktenbarcode)       
        akte.delete()
        akte_list = Akte.objects.filter(containerId__Containernr=container)
        Anzahl_Akten =Akte.objects.filter(containerId__Containernr=container).count
        return render(
            request,
            'app/aktentabelle.html', 
            {
            'form':form, 
            'title':'About',
            'akte_list':akte_list,
            'anzahl':Anzahl_Akten,
            'container':container,
            'aktenform':z,
            'status':status,
            'closecontainerform': closecontainerform,
            'date':datetime.now().date,
            }
            )
```

Comment: it will be better, if you show view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're generating the markup for the modal dialog for each iteration of the for loop, however you're not changing the `id` value. The `id` is always set to `myModal`, when it should be unique.

Thus, when you click the button it is likely that you will always see dialog corresponding to the the first `id` encountered.

You can use Django's `forloop.counter` variable to give each modal a unique id

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal-{{ forloop.counter }}"
```

and do the same when referencing from the button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-{{ forloop.counter }}"
```

You must also ensure that your form submit handler `onclick="form_submit()"` submits the correct form depending upon the loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete a specific row, firstly, you have to pick up the `object id`.
For example, with `checkboxes` or anything else which let to get `id(s)`

Then, you need to call this `id` in your class/function and you could write something like this :

```
Akte.objects.filter(id=id).delete()
```

Comment: i thought in my for loop i always submit the right object id when i submit             <input type="hidden" name="aktenbarcode" value="{{Akte.Aktenbarcode}}" />     to my view